# Link a content types field to the user profile

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I would like to link the output of a field(say WRITTEN BY:Name) in the content type (say ARTICLE) to the user profile.

Comment: This question is a better fit for our sister site [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at [Entity API](http://drupal.org/project/entity) and [Entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference).

Consider these modules over the references module (as stated in references module):

> References will most probably be deprecated in the near future in
>   favor of Entity Reference, which should probably be considered first
>   on fresh D7 projects. Another, more radical, alternative would be the
>   Relation module.

**Update:**
Here are the required steps:

- go to the content type manage fields page. e.g.
  `admin/structure/types/manage/page/fields`
- Under `Add new field` section choose `Type of data to store.` to be `Entity Reference` and for the widget, select whichever works to you. Then click `Save`.
- From the `Field settings` page, set `Target type` to `User`, then configure the remaining settings to fit your purpose and save the settings.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Comment: I've add the steps to the comment. Kindly recheck.

Comment: I went that far, i'm starting to have problems after that..... i will work through the night and say if i have any issues. thanks for your time and support.

Comment: Don't hesitate to share any issues you might face. I'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [user reference](http://drupal.org/project/references) field and link to the User profile.

Cheers!!!